# Como inserir código Javascript no banco de dados?

Tags: php, mysql

Estou criando uma função *bbcode* para um blog que estou fazendo e queria saber se é possível (e seguro) eu inserir códigos Javascript dentro do meu banco de dados.

Estou trabalhando com MySql.

Outra questão, não consigo inserir aspas simples (que estão dentro do `textarea`) dentro do banco de dados.

#### Esse é o código que estou usando para inserção

```
$sql="INSERT INTO artigo values";
$sql.="('null','".$titulo."','".$mensagem."', NOW())";
```

Comment: Por que você não usa arquivos `.js` mesmo?

Comment: Resolvi, tratrando a string dessa forma: $mensagem_escape = str_replace("'", "\'", $mensagem);

Comment: @Odair Use `mysql_real_escape_string` em vez de `str_replace` http://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php

Comment: Valeu @EmersonRochaLuiz vou alterar aqui, muito obrigado pela ajuda!

Comment: costumo colocar no BD em formato de encode de base64 os codigos de linguagens...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A resposta disso depende. Se seguro para seu banco de dados, ou se seguro para sua aplicação.

### Banco de dados: principal ataque SQL Injection

Se você escapar caracteres e remover códigos que poderiam causar um `SQL Injection`, será seguro para seu banco de dados.

Todas as linguagens que trabalha com banco de dados oferecem recursos para evitar esse tipo de ataque. Leia a respeito da sua linguagem para saber mais. **Não é complexo evitar esse tipo de ataque.**

### Aplicação: principal ataque Cross-site scripting (XSS) persistente

Essa pergunta é bem complexa e depende de muita experiência com navegadores e forma de como uma falha pode ser explorada. Se você não sabe exatamente o que está fazendo. Há uma chance enorme de uma falha poder ser explorada, pois você pode permitir um código `javascript` para fazer algo inofensivo, mas as pessoas usarem para roubar os cookies de alguém que está visualizando a página ande o código javascript delas está disponível, e o código poderia enviar os cookies para outros sites. Esse é so um dos exemplos. Mas existem muitos outros.

**É complexo, senão impossível, evitar esse tipo de ataque. Somente usuários confiáveis deveria permitir inserir javascript sem uma validação pesada.**

Recomendo fortemente a qualquer pessoa interessada ver o vídeo [Douglas Crockford: Principles of Security](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zKuFu19LgZA) que explica o quão complicado é isso e dá uma idéia de como evitar.

### Visão geral

**A não ser que tenha motivos fortes para fazer isso e saiba as implicações, ou confie fortemente em quem vai inserir o código javascript, não faça isso**. Por padrão CMSs, como Joomla e Wordpress não permitem inserir javascript, mas há meios de permitir que javascript seja inserido nos artigos, mas é a pessoa que administra o CMS é que decide habilitar isso.

Comment: Cara, valeu pelo feedback! Serei eu mesmo que incluirei os .js no banco de dados, então é seguro! haha Valeu mesmo.

Answer (score 3):

#### 1. **Sim, é possível**.

Código JavaScript é somente texto. Tecnicamente, não tem problema nenhum armazenar no banco de dados. Se é recomendável ou se é a melhor solução, é outra questão.

#### 2. É seguro? Depende.

Depende completamente da utilização que você pretende dar a esse código. De onde ele vem, para onde ele vai, e como ele é utilizado.

No **banco de dados**, não há ambiente de execução do JavaScript. É seguro. Como dito acima, é apenas mais uma *string* de texto. Você precisará tomar as precauções comuns a qualquer outro conteúdo de texto, notadamente o *escape*, evitando vulnerabilidades que independem do texto ser "código JavaScript" ou qualquer outro tipo de texto.

Já na **aplicação**, depende muito, variando de um extremo a outro: conforme a utilização pode ser perigoso ou seguro.

Para analisar, é preciso começar considerando: Como você pretende usar esse código? Quem poderá abastecer o banco com esse código?

O perigo de usar código de JavaScript gerado pelo usuário é que um usuário mal-intencionado pode facilmente programar para que uma requisição HTTP seja feita, disparando outras funções de sua aplicação (por exemplo, simular o efeito de um clique em "Curtir", enviar o cookie de autenticação para um servidor remoto, *et cetera*).

Comment: Certo, muito obrigado pelo feedback, estou tentando inserir mas não consigo, não insere a parte do código javascript pq?

Comment: Odair, só dá para responder se você colocar o código que não está funcionando na pergunta. Edite sua pergunta, e inclua o código PHP que você está usando para tentar inserir no banco de dados. Provavelmente está faltando fazer um *escape* na *string* que contém o código.

Comment: Certo @J.Bruni muito obrigado pelo feedback, identifiquei o problema que me impedia de inserir, era as aspas simples no meu bbcode. Mas como faz esse escape? Ah eu editei a pergunta, como vc recomendou! :D